# Interpretation of Chi Square Goodness of Fit Test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, chi-squared-test, inference, proportion

Suppose you run a chi square GOF test on a categorical variable with 2 levels and you reject the null (p= p0). If phat > p0, can you conclude that the population proportion is not only not equal to the hypothesized value, but is actually greater?

My guess is that you can say this because if the true proportion was less than p0, the chi square statistic would be even larger (and hence more unlikely to occur if H0 was true). However, I can't recall having seen this interpretation, so I'm a little wary of it.

I know this is probably a simple question, but I could not find any mention of it from an internet search, so even pointing me to a good reference would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: testing difference in proportions is not the same thing as goodness of fit ! which of the two you want answered ?

Comment: My understanding is that when you run a chi-square goodness of fit on a single categorical variable with 2 levels, the hypotheses are: H0: p=p0 vs H1:p is not equal to p0. I am not totally sure what you mean by a "difference in proportions" (since there are 2 interpretations of this), but this is what I was referring to

Comment: The text of the question says true / population proportion. In statistics,  p-value is the probability of rejecting a null hypothesis which is true. If you edit your  question and indicate sample of your data, then it  it may be more convenient for someone to respond accurately.

Comment: I'm not understanding your objections/concerns. First, I'm not referring to any p-value in my original post, so I don't understand why you raised this issue. Second, in the context of my problem, I am in fact testing if the population proportion is equal to a specific value, so my original statement is exactly what I meant to say. Third, your comment that I "indicate sample of your data" is unclear to me. Are you suggesting I include the sample data I am testing? I could, I suppose, but my question is really about the general hypothesis test itself.

Comment: The objective  (can you conclude) you stated in para-1 of your question is different from hypothesis of equality of  two proportions ?  The latter hypothesis for  testing requires a  t-test of difference in two proportion and I do not think that a chi- square Goodness of Fit test could be useful for this purpose. I presume that there are several missing links in the question.

Comment: Good point. Let me try to state my problem in a formal, precise way and see what I'm missing:

Comment: Good point. Let me try to state my problem in a formal, precise way and see what I'm missing: #1) I have one categorical with 2 levels.  #2) My parameter of interest is "p", the population percentage for a particular level of my categorical variable.   #3) For the chi-square goodness of fit test, my hypotheses are H0: p = p0 and Ha:p is not equal to p0 (where p0 is the hypothesized value I believe p to have under the null hypothesis).

Comment: #4) My test statistic is the chi-square test statistic, x0  #5) My p-value = P( chi-square >=  x0)   #6) If p-value>= alpha, we fail to reject H0 and if p-value <alpha we reject H0 and decide there is sufficient evidence to conclude that p is not equal to p0.    *All this we are in agreement of, right?*

Comment: Things give a better look now. However, a little effort is necessary to have better understanding of problem.The "proportion" - "P" and "p-value" for significance test must be understood. Unless, I examine your data and summary output, it is unlikely that I could help you understand working of chi-square statistic. The edit of your question may be useful for the users who wish to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the answer now. The chi-square test for goodness of fit only tests is the counts are from a binomial distribution (it is not a test on the value of the population proportion, per se).
My mistake was in thinking that any process with 2 outcomes had to be a binomial process (forgetting of course the assumption of independent Bernoulli trials)